# code for pausing a macro for a limited time period

Tags: excel, vba

excel vba macro sports simulation

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.wait

Answer (score 1):

Use "Application.Wait" function. In below example, your considering the current time and making the macro wait for 10 seconds.

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
```

Comment: This answer was just what I was looking for.  I put the code into the macro and it accomplished exactly what I needed.  Thank you PerlBatch !!